# Mudblazor interactivity broken in .net8 with new template

Tags: .net-8.0

I can't get interactive mudblazor components to work on interactive pages in .net 8 after creating a new project with the .net 8 template. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have a .net 7 project that I would like to upgrade but I am not even going to try until I get this working. I have tried a lot of Blazor component libraries, but I like MB the best and really want this to work.

I tried InteractiveServer, InteractiveAuto, and InteractiveWebAssembly. I tried various includes of blazor components (VS 2022 said I didn't need them). I specifically tested dialog and menu.

Answer (score 2):

OK! so with mudblazor components in .net 8.0 you can not run the application in some of the rendering options added to .net 8.0.

For most of your components like buttons and dialogs you need to add the fallowing to your MainLayout.razor file

```
<MudThemeProvider @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
<MudSnackbarProvider @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
<MudDialogProvider @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

And set up javascript for mudblazor by adding the fallowing line to the body section of app.razor:

```
<script src="_content/MudBlazor/MudBlazor.min.js"></script>
```

I did not remove:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
```

and dont forget to set up your components in program.cs and your using statements in _imports.razor IE:

```
builder.Services.AddMudServices();
```

This page is the ONLY page I have found that helps with my issues, so feel free to look into this as well as anything I have personally done to get functionality to work is here https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/issues/7774

I'm currently still working on getting themes to work as that appears to break my functionality as soon as I add a customTheme class, but I'm not 100% about that, maybe something in my actual custom theme is breaking it.

Given a re-read I think this is only relevant to starting a default razor .net 8.0 project and adding mud. My apologies but ill leave it up just in case.

Comment: +1. In dotnet8 blazor webapp, adding the @rendermode="InteractiveServer" in each provider element (in MyMudProviders.razor file e.g. <MudDialogProvider @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />) was the solution for me. the popup was opening fine when global interactive server enabled, but when using per component interactivity the popup did not open. After adding interactivity attribute to the providers as mentioned above, the popup started showing up.

Answer (score 0):

The templates do not have the latest nuget packages - simply update them - ensure that you install them only in the right project (i.e. some go in the server project - some go in the client) and everything will be fine. This should work with all of the new templates but I only tried with the Global interactive with individual accounts options.

Answer (score 0):

Update nuget packages in the server project,
Update nuget packages in the client project

Make sure you **clean and rebuild** the project after updating the nuget packages or it still wont work!

Thanks [@Angman777](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10516045/angman-777?tab=topactivity) for the post and answer, it wasnt working for me until i cleaned and rebuilt. Probably should have know to do so but got he heads up from here  https://github.com/MudBlazor/Templates/issues/453